# checkbox в yii 2.0

Tags: php, yii2, checkbox

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в представлении вывести в ActiveForm checkboxList, значение которые являются объектами модели переданными из контроллера? И как их потом считать в контроллере?

---

```
  $item = new ReqModel();
if ($item->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $item->validate()) {
        $yes='OK'; 
            foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
                $NEWMAS[]=$key;
}
}
return $this->render('antivirus-result', ['yes'=>$NEWMAS]);
```

Во view, просто вывожу через forech

```
foreach ($yes as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

тогда вот что она выводит. Не понимаю(...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Объекты модели - это сущность PHP. Значения в checkbox может быть первичный ключ, по которому потом PHP получает нужный объект модели. Глупо сразу брать в руки фреймворк, не зная как работает WEB.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если например модель `Item`, в ней есть поля `id` и `checkbox_id`. И есть модель `CheckboxValues` с полями `id` и `name` в которой мы храним все возможные значения чекбоксов.

В контроллере:

```
public function actionEdit($id)
{
    $item = Item::findOne($id);

    // Сохраняем
    if ($item->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($item->save()) {
            Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', 'Значение сохранено успешно');
        } else {
            Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'Ошибка сохранения в базу');
        }
    }

    // Получаем массив значений чекбоксов
    $checkboxValues = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(CheckboxValues::find()->all(), 'id', 'name');

    return $this->render('edit', [
        'item' => $item,
        'checkboxValues' => $checkboxValues
    ]);
}
```

Во вьюхе (`edit.php`):

```
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Html;

$form = ActiveForm::begin(['method' => 'post']);

echo $form->field($item, 'checkbox_id')->checkboxList($checkboxValues);

echo Html::submitButton('Сохранить');

ActiveForm::end();
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял это '$item = Item::findOne($id);

    // Сохраняем
    if ($item->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($item->save()) {
            Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', 'Значение сохранено успешно');
        } else {
            Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'Ошибка сохранения в базу');
        }
    }' у нас для обработки POST запроса. Только вот что мы тогда на get передаем? Пустую модель Item?

Comment: @Игнат , на get мы передаём id модели Item

Comment: А зачем они там нужны? Мы же ведь модель Item используем только для того чтобы в ней потом перенести из view в контроллер данные в post запросе. Какие еще id?

Comment: @Игнат в модели `Item` в этом примере хранится выбранное значение пользователем. И в примере представлен пример экшена `edit` - редактирование юзером своего значения которое раньше где-то уже выбралось и сохранилось. `Id` - это поле в таблице, идентификатор записи.

Comment: Значит я всё правильно понял. Спасибо за терпение. И огромное спасибо за такое подробное объяснение.

Answer (score 0):

@Pa3Py6aka Я создал новую  модель
`

```
namespace frontend\models;
use yii\base\Model;
class ReqModel extends Model
{
public $id ;
public $checkbox_id;

public function rules()
{

        return [

            [['id', 'checkbox_id', 'safe'],
        ];
    }
    }`
```

в контроллере

```
public function actionAntivirus($id)
    {
         $id = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('id');
        $models = TestRes2GeneralInf::find()->where('id_TestRes1_all_types = :id', [':id' => $id])->all();
        $result = ArrayHelper::map($models, 'id', 'Name'); /////////////////////
        $item=new ReqModel();

        return $this->render('antivirus', [
//            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'models' => $item, 'result'=>$result,
        ]);
    }
```

В представление

```
           <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                    'id' => 'antivirus-test-results',
                    'action' => ['/test-results/antivirus-result'],
                    'options' => ['method' => 'post']
                ]);
<?php                                        
           echo $form->field($models, 'checkbox_id')->checkboxList($result);
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Результаты испытаний', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'contact-button']) ?>
                </div>
                <?php ActiveForm::end();?>
```

И всё равно ничего не пашет ((( Вроде всё правильно описал, понимаю каждую строчку, но в чем ошибка?

Comment: Что хранится в `TestRes2GeneralInf`? Что именно не пашет? В модели кстати в rules надо написать вот так: `[['id', 'checkbox_id'], 'safe']`.

Comment: @Pa3Py6aka [['id', 'checkbox_id'], 'safe']- ДА! Именно из за это не работало. Ура! :D. Только теперь вопрос как их обработать в контроллере?

Comment: нужно сохранить выбранное значение в `ReqModel `? Тогда в контроллере в этом же самом экшине добавь сохранение данных, в своём примере выше я писал как (`if ($item->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) ... `)

Comment: @Pa3Py6aka Но ведь при нажатие на submit я перехожу на другой `Action`. И я думал, что это в нём нужно делать обработку полученных post данных. Разве не так?

Comment: А ну да, я про action упустил у тебя, ты прав, в твоём случае обработку надо сделать в `actionAntivirusResult()`

Comment: @Pa3Py6aka Ну так всё равно ошибку пишет

Comment: Какую ошибку? где?

Comment: @Pa3Py6aka Я тут в виде как ответ отправил, код. Он на валидацию не проверяет. false возвращает походу

Answer (score 0):

@Pa3Py6aka

```
    if ($item->load(\Yii::$app->request->post('antivirus'))) {
           for ($i=1; $i <= count($arrayName) ; $i++) { 
                $tmp=TestRes5::find()->where('id_testres2_general_inf = :id', [':id' => $item[$i]->id])->all();
                $testres5[]=$tmp;
                $tmp=new TestRes5();
            }  
}
```

Он сюда даже не заходит. Не валидно походу. Вот что в модели

```
<?php
namespace frontend\models;

use yii\base\Model;

class ReqModel extends Model
{
    public $id ;
    public $checkbox_id;

    public function rules()
{
    return [

        [['id', 'checkbox_id'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
}
```

Comment: В load надо передавать массив параметров, то есть надо не `$item->load(\Yii::$app->request->post('antivirus'))`, а `$item->load(\Yii::$app->request->post())`

Comment: @Pa3Py6aka Если я ваш вариант пробую, он ошибку выдаёт, а если свой, не пойму что он выводит тогда. Код опишу ниже

Comment: @Pa3Py6aka У меня всё заработало!!! Оказывается в ` \ `  символе была проблема перед `Yii`. Огромное огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: Советую использовать какую-нибудь хорошую IDE для написания кода, например phpStorm, тогда таких глупых ошибок не будет)

Comment: Я в php совсем зелён. Спасибо за подсказку)